# Не могу подключится к FTP серверу

Tags: phpstorm, ftp

Всем привет, в общем проблема в том, что не могу попасть на сайт по FTP, использую fileZilla и phpstorm.
FileZilla говорит, что соединение установлено, ожидание приглашения... и после таймаута всё повторяется и так до бесконечности, в phpstorm тоже самое.Хотя на сайт можно спокойно зайти!

Пробовал заходить на рандомные ftp в сети, работает, и через браузер и через клиент.Подскажите в чём может быть проблема ?

P.S ftp рабочий(в смысле сервер компании), там работает всё норм.

Comment: Возможно у вас sftp который висит на 22 порту по умолчанию либо используется не стандартный порт. Выложите лог с Filezilla во время коннекта к серверу.

Comment: эти логи? Статус: Определение IP-адреса для shkett.ycdv.ru
Статус: Соединяюсь с 188.128.28.10:21...
Статус: Соединение установлено, ожидание приглашения...
Ошибка: Соединение прервано после 20 секунд неактивности
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
Статус: Ожидание повтора...
Статус: Определение IP-адреса для shkett.ycdv.ru
Статус: Соединяюсь с 188.128.28.10:21...
Статус: Соединение установлено, ожидание приглашения...  ЗЫ у меня ubuntu 16.04 если что

Comment: Если это сервер компании и на рабочем месте доступ к нему есть, а извне(у вас дома) нету,  то возможно доступ имеет, к примеру, только внутренняя корпоративная сеть (vpn)?